# Atmosphere - Storing attributes on the AtmosphereResource

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I need to store some serverside values against a suspended request and I'm not sure how I should go about it. I'd like the attributes to be cleaned up when the suspended connection is no longer live on the client. I expected `AtmosphereResource` to have `setAttribute(name,value)` and `getAttribute(name)` methods but they don't exist. I've thought of three possible approaches:

1. Use `AtmosphereResource.getRequest().setAttribute(name,value)`
2. Provide my own `AtmosphereResource` implementation and add the methods there (backed by a concurrent map).
3. Have some form of listener / interceptor that listens for create / destroy of AtmosphereResource and maintain my own serverside state using `AtmosphereResource.uuid()`.

Questions:

1. Are there any issues with using the request attributes of the suspended request? Will this work for all transport methods?
2. Are there any examples of providing a custom `AtmosphereResource` implementation?
3. If I provide my own `AtmosphereResource` implementation, will it live for the lifetime of the suspended request? Will this work for all transport methods (eg long-polling)?
4. Is there a hook to get events for create / destroy? I've looked at `AtmosphereInterceptor` but can only see `inspect` and `postInspect` events.
5. Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem with a `AtmosphereResourceEventListener` which creates and destroys a session per `AtmosphereResource`.

I'm surprised that other people haven't had this problem, it seems like a pretty normal requirement to want a session per client connection.

If anyone is interested in my solution, some interesting classes are:

- [AtmosphereResourceEventListenerImpl.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/internal/AtmosphereResourceEventListenerImpl.java)
- [AtmosphereSessionManagerImpl.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/internal/AtmosphereSessionManagerImpl.java)
- [AtmosphereHandlerImpl.java](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/services/internal/AtmosphereHandlerImpl.java)

Comment: might want to do a pull request with your proposal, or at least file an RFE so this mechanism can be added. Thanks -- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Hi Jeanfrancois, my solution is quite custom to my implementation since session creation is fired by my custom AtmosphereHandler. I'm pretty sure that a generic solution could be done with a AtmosphereResourceEventListener. I just wasn't entirely confident in the AtmosphereResource life cycle for a uuid across multiple gets for long-polling.